# The period of the permutation of a period sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

Given that 
$$
  a^\infty = \{ a_i\} _{i = 0}^{\infty} = (a_0a_1a_2\ldots)
$$
is a peroidic sequence over $\mathrm{GF}(q)$ and its period is $p$. Let $s$ a positive interger and define
$$
  a^\infty(s) = \{ a_{is}\} _{i = 0}^{\infty} = (a_0a_sa_{2s}\ldots)
$$
The question is to prove that if $\mathrm{gcd}(p, s) = 1$ then the period of $a^\infty(s)$ is $p$ as well.

I have worked out that the period of $a^\infty(s)$ must be a factor of $p$ since $(a_0, a_s, a_{2s}, \ldots, a_{(p-1)s})$ are the permutation of $(a_0, a_1, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{(p-1)})$. That is, $a_{(p+i)s} = a_{is}$.
However, I have no idea how to prove that the period of $a^\infty(s)$ is $p$ exactly.